# How to remove unused characters from a list of strings

Tags: python, python-2.7

For example, my list is:

```
list_1 =  [ '[1234,', '4567,', '19234,', '786222]' ]
```

and the expected output is:

```
list_1 = [1234, 4567, 19234, 786222]
```

Comment: How did you end up with that list to start with? It looks like you've taken a list representation and split it on spaces; why?!

Comment: Are you sure that's your list? Who gave it to you? It's horrible.

Answer (score 6):

Frankly, the easiest way to get a list of integers back out of that is to put it back together as a string representing a list:

```
>>> list_1 = ['[1234,', '4567,', '19234,', '786222]']

>>> list_repr = ' '.join(list_1)
>>> list_repr
'[1234, 4567, 19234, 786222]'
```

And then feed it through [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval(list_repr)
[1234, 4567, 19234, 786222]
```

In the likely event that you got `list_1` by using the `split` method on a string that *already* represented a list in the first place, I'm sure you can figure out how to shorten this process...

Comment: You always surprise me. I like the use of `literal_eval`.

Comment: @PeterWood I'm not sure surprise is something to aim for, but thanks! Given the format of the OP's input, I strongly suspect they got it via `split` anyway.

Comment: By surprising, I mean you often approach problems in unorthodox ways with orthodox python, if that makes sense. So, you think outside the box and then do it properly, the 'one way'.

Comment: @PeterWood that I will definitely take as a compliment, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) the bad characters and convert to `int`.

```
>>> [int(s.strip("[],")) for s in list_1]
[1234, 4567, 19234, 786222]
```

Comment: This is the best answer. `ast.literal_eval` feels to "hacky" to me.

Answer (score 2):

Using Python 2:

```
>>> map(int, ''.join(list_1).strip('[]').split(','))
[1234, 4567, 19234, 786222]
```

In Python 3 `map` returns a map object which only lazily evaluates. To create the list we need to be explicit. This is a good thing, more efficient and general:

```
>>> list(map(int, ''.join(list_1).strip('[]').split(',')))
[1234, 4567, 19234, 786222]
```

Comment: This is a really good answer. But can you add a line stating that it is valid only for python2 as it in python3 `map` returns a map object. I know that the question is tagged with python2, but the note will serve as a deterrent to future visitors of your answer.

Comment: Now the answer looks complete. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [translate](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate) to remove your unwanted characters.

```
>>> [int(s.translate(None,"[],")) for s in list_1]
[1234, 4567, 19234, 786222]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the set of "bad" characters up front, you can also filter all digits from each string and then convert the result to an integer:

```
>>> list_1 =  [ '[1234,', '4567,', '19234,', '786222]' ]
>>> [int(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), s)) for s in list_1]
[1234, 4567, 19234, 786222]
```